# Which of these integrals has the largest value?

Tags: calculus, integration

This question is designed to be done without calculating any of the integrals.

> Which of the following has the largest value?
>
> (A) $\displaystyle\int_0^2 (x^2-4)\sin^8(\pi x)\,dx$
>
> (B) $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} (2+\cos x)^3\,dx$
>
> (C) $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{100}x\,dx$
>
> (D) $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi (3-\sin x)^6\,dx$
>
> (E) $\displaystyle\int_0^{8\pi}108(\sin^3x-1)\,dx$

My thoughts:

For $x\in[0,2]$, $x^2-4\leq 0$, which eliminates (A), since certainly some of the others are positive.

For (B), the integrals $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos x\,dx$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^3x\,dx$ are both $0$, so the integral becomes $\int_0^{2\pi}(8+2\cos^2x)\,dx$.

(C) will have a small positive value, and cannot be the answer since it is clear that (B)$>$(C).

(D) looks like it will be the biggest.

(E) will have a large negative value.

**Without calculating the integrals, how can I be sure that (D) $>$ (B)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have $6\cos^2x$ in (B). Anyway $\cos x\le1$, so the integral in (B) can be said to be less than $\int_0^{2\pi}(2+1)^3 dx=2\pi27$. At the same time in (D) $$\int_0^\pi(3-\sin x)^6dx\ge\int_0^\pi2^6 dx=\pi64$$
Since $54\lt 64$, it means that the integral in (D) is larger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you be sure that $(D)>(B)$. $$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi (3-\sin x)^6\,dx>2^6\times {\pi }>201$$ On the other hand $$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} (2+\cos x)^3\,dx<3^3\times {2}{\pi}<170$$